# dot product and 3 cross products

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

How would I solve an equation involving dot product with cross product of $3$ vectors?

$\vec{a} = [-2, 1] $

$\vec{b} = [0, 1]$

$k_1 = 4$

$k_2 = 20$

The expression to solve is:
$\dfrac {(\vec{b} \cdot \vec{b}) }{ k_1 }+ \dfrac {(\vec{b} \cdot \vec{a} \times \vec{b} \times \vec{a}) } {k_2}$

In the above expression

**. refers to dot product and 
 x refers to cross product.**

The answer should be $\dfrac {13} {20}$

The $\dfrac{(\vec{b} \cdot \vec{b}) }{ k_1}$ is $\dfrac 1 4$

How is $\dfrac{(\vec{b} \cdot \vec{a} \times \vec{b} \times \vec{a}) }{ k_2 } = \dfrac {8} {20}$?

Thanks.

Comment: Your vectors $a$ and $b$ have different dimension, how we can define the dot or cross product between them?

Comment: @EmilioNovati Fixed the dimensions. Please go ahead.

Comment: Well. And how you define the cross product of two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: [Cross Product is not Associative](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cross_Product_is_not_Associative)

Comment: $ a_x * b_y - a_y * b_x $

Comment: That would result in a scalar, which cannot be crossproduct-ed with another vector.